# Error in Burnside's "Theory of groups of finite order"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

In W. Burnside's "Theory of groups of finite order" on page 16 where is proposition that for all permutable $S_q$ and $S_r$ if $S_p=S_qS_r$ then $\text{order}(S_p)=\text{lcm}(\text{order}(S_q),\text{order}(S_r))$. But it is not true even in cyclic groups. What I do not understand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are wrong. Burnside does not write that. He writes

"and in that case the order of $S_p$ is equal to **or a factor of** the least common multiple of the orders of $S_q$ and $S_r$."

Comment: My personal recommendation is not to read Burnside's book unless you have an excellent command of the English language, particularly as spoken in the early 1900s. For example, to introduce the notation for the group generated by a set of elements, he states: "It is convenient here to explain a notation that enables us to avoid an otherwise rather cumbrous phraseology."

Comment: "Avoid an otherwise rather cumbrous phraseology": task failed successfully.